# get raw value from URL parameter in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, urldecode

I've got a react component that allows users to unsubscribe from an email, and there's a hash being passed along with the unsubscribe link so we know what mail item the request is associated with. Unfortunately the hash sometimes has some URL-specific characters in it, like `+` and `/`. Right now I'm doing something like this to get the data from the hash to pass to the unsubscribe service:

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
const campaignId = query.get('campaign') ?? '';
```

the problem is that when I pass the `campaign` in to the unsubscribe, and (for example) the `campaig` hash has a `+` in it, that gets converted to a space.

Is there a better way to get this string, or a way to "un-encode" it?

Comment: Try the `getParams` function here, might be what you want: https://gomakethings.com/getting-all-query-string-values-from-a-url-with-vanilla-js/

Comment: Have you looked at `decodeURIComponent()` or `encodeURIComponent()`? Maybe encoding the `campaign` first would prevent the `+` to be converted to a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something fairly inelegant-- but it works. I used the `decodeURIComponent()` as suggested by @ofri in the comments above, but the spaces were not being converted back to `+`. So this is what I came up with:

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
const campaignId = query.get('campaignId') ?? '';

// then when we create the axios payload:
campaignId : decodeURIComponent(campaignId.replace(/ /g, '+'))
```